# J-1 visa expiry date

Tags: j1-visas

I have just received my J-1 visa (short-term scholar). On the visa it says "Expiry date: 14 November". My flight back is on the 20th of November. Do I understand correctly that even though the visa expires on the 14th, I get additional 30 days to leave the country? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 10):

A US visa is solely for entry. The visa's expiration date is simply the last day you can use the visa to enter the US; it has nothing to do with how long you can stay in the US. So for example, you can enter on the day the visa expires, and stay for potentially years, if you remain in a valid J-1 program that whole time (with a valid DS-2019 and remain in the designated program).

J-1 status lasts for 30 days after you complete the program. So it depends on when your program completes, which you have not stated.

Comment: The program completes on 14 November as well.

Comment: By the way, here's a follow-up question: Does what you said mean that after  I enter the US I can leave and re-enter as many times as I want before the 14 November? I probably won't but hypothetically if I wanted to go to Canada for a few days, would that be possible?

Comment: @user67085 no, you cannot leave and reenter the US after your program ends.  Once you leave the US, your grace period ends.  To reenter after that, you'd need to use a different visa, such as a B-2.

Comment: I was asking about leaving and re-entering before the program ends.

Comment: @user67085: You can enter as long as you have a valid visa. Assuming your visa is a multiple-use visa, you can use it multiple times to enter before its expiration date. It's also possible to go to Canada for a few days and re-enter without a valid visa, under automatic revalidation, as long as you are continuing your program.

Comment: My visa says "Entries: M", I assume this means what you described as a multiple-use visa, which means that I can leave and re-enter at any point before the end of the program and the expiry of the visa, which happens to be the same date (14 November). Could you confirm whether I am right?

Comment: @user67085: yes

Answer (score -1):

From:

https://j1visa.state.gov/participants/common-questions/

> Upon completion of your exchange program, you have a grace period of 30 days to depart the United States.

Note that typically you are not allowed to re-enter in those 30 days - even across the border from Canada or Mexico.

Comment: Yes. I understand. My question is: is completion of my exchange programme equivalent to expiry date on the visa? Or should the visa already have these 30 days added to it?

Comment: Your visa expires on 14 November. After that, you are granted up to 30 days grace, to leave.

Comment: Okay thanks! I just wasn't sure what the term "grace" means exactly!

Comment: The thirty days are counted from the *end of the program.*  The expiration date of the visa is (as with *all* US visas) completely unrelated to the date by which the bearer must leave the US.  -1.

Answer (score -2):

If your J1 is expiring you don't to worry much you can still work in US on sponsored E2 non investor visa. I know ALTEN Calsoft Labs offer E2 visa for French nationals

Comment: Welcome to the site. Thanks for trying to help but I am afraid you missed the point of this question. It is not about working on an E2 visa. Can you edit your answer so it fits the question?

Comment: People, do not flag this for moderator attention, it already got that. If you think it is not enough of an answer, flag it as such.